# Spring session with back end api's instead of JDBC

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I have been exploring on spring-session framework for session management in our application, and we want to store session in database. I understand that spring provides implementation with JDBC and we can configure our own DataSource. The problem I'm facing is that we don't have direct access to db and need to make web service call to do any sort of crud operations.

So, is there a way to integrate spring-session to consume web services for session related crud operations in db ?

Another question is, can we change the schema for session related tables. I know that we can change the table names, but is it possible to add or remove further columns in the given tables ?

Comment: Ofcourse just provide your own repository, but if you need to make web service calls don't expect it to be very performant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can employ your custom session repository fairly easy - use `@EnableSpringHttpSession` (which imports `SpringHttpSessionConfiguration`) to configure common Spring Session components and register your `SessionRepository` implementation `@Bean`.

Regarding more advanced customization of schema used by `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository`, this was considered during implementation of JDBC support however decision was made not to provide this initially. If you need this feature please consider creating an feature request in [Spring Session issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues).

Comment: thanks for your reply @Vedran, i have figured out  JdbcOperationsSessionRepository and created a small poc as well. However, web session use case is on hold and we may be using some other framework, probably apache shiro along with authentication

Comment: You could also use Spring Security to manage authentication and authorization aspects of your application. Spring Session's focus is user session management and the two work well together. There's a [sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/security) for such use case in the Spring Session project itself.